# Viewing a "log" of new (distinct) events in a database

Tags: database, database-design

I have an application which has several unrelated tables in its db. I'll explain by using an "auto-updating" version of the SO homepage as an example, so lets say I have the tables "**users**", "**comments**" and "**questions**".

The homepage client side needs to periodically poll the server, and get a log of all the new "events" that have happened. I.e., I'd like to display (somehow) the new questions, comments and users that have been added to SO since the last poll.

On way would be to simply keep a variable on the client side containing the last index of each of my tables, send it to the server, and have the server send me the new users, comments and questions.

**The problem is,** what happens when I add a new type of information, say, votes. Now I have to store another variable on the client-side, and the server has to poll another table. And so on, for every new type of information I keep.

I'm looking for a solution that helps me avoid this.

Another problem - say I'd like to see all the "events" that have happened since last time, but sorted according to when they took place.

One direction I had is to have a single "events" table, which contains the info about when each event happened. I can then poll only this table, and get a list of all the new events that have happened. The problem is that each event is pretty different (a new comment has different columns than a new upvote, etc.) So I'm not sure how to implement this, or if this is even a good idea.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can solve this? This seems like something that would come up a lot, but I don't really have much experience with databases, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to future proof via database design. While this can be done through something an [EVA model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) I caution against that because the value its adds tend to not be worth the cost.

Instead you should model the database as closely to reality as possible and not how you intend to use it.

Then use SQL to project the data to how you need it. You can do this by statements that will either deliver the meta data that you need

e.g.

```
Select 
  Count(ID) , 'Comments' Type
From 
  Comments
Where
  lastUpdate > #InputParamter1#
UNION Select 
  Count(ID) , 'Questions' Type
From 
  Questions
Where
  lastUpdate > #InputParamter1#
```

Or (and this doesn't get used Often enough)

Return more than one result set from your database in one go

```
Select 
    userid,
    ComentText
From 
    Comments
 Where
      lastUpdate > #InputParamter1#;
Select
    userId,
    Questions,
    Tags
From 
    Questions
 Where
      lastUpdate > #InputParamter1#
```

That said you will still have to write some code if you add new stuff but it should be limited to updating your sql, adding new containers for your data and then code to display to the end users and then to validate and store it.

Honestly the idea of adding new stuff requiring some work doesn't seem that awful to me.